# Export to shapefile to csv from spatial join code

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, convert, csv, spatial-join

I have created some code to perform a a one to many spatial keeping all rows, I would like to export the resulting shapefile to CSV as that is the required format for the program the the data will be used in?

Spatial Join code:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = r"U:\GIO\Geospatial_Services\ANALYTICS\Tools\Parliamentary"
env.overwrite = True

Parcel = r"U:\GIO\Geospatial_Services\ANALYTICS\Tools\Parliamentary\MP_Cut_Many.shp"
int_shp = r"U:\GIO\Geospatial_Services\ANALYTICS\Tools\Parliamentary\MP.shp"

output_speed_fc = r"U:\GIO\Geospatial_Services\ANALYTICS\Tools\Parliamentary\MP_Join_2.shp"

arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(Parcel, int_shp, output_speed_fc, join_operation="JOIN_ONE_TO_MANY", join_type="KEEP_COMMON", match_option="INTERSECT")

print 'worked'
```

The CSV conversions I have tried before haven't worked, got to convert to DBF, I am using Arcgis10.1

Answer (score 1):

I have worked it out I have added this to it

```
arcpy.ImportToolbox("U:\GIO\Geospatial_Services\ANALYTICS\Tools\Table To Excel Tool\Table To Excel Tool.tbx")

arcpy.TableToExcel_xls("U:\GIO\Geospatial_Services\ANALYTICS\Tools\Parliamentary\MP_Join_4.shp","CSV_MPJOIN", "CSV")
```

The toolbox imported is a downloaded Table to excel toolbox which I found on our system which I just imported into arcpy and used that tool

http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=cbb7b0ea4c014dd8bc2832f9be1e2d03

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Export Feature Attributes to ASCII](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//005p0000003v000000) which is in the Spatial Statistics > Utilities toolbox.

You can choose your delimiter (space, comma, tab), choose the fields you want to export and specify if you want to export your field names to the CSV file.

To use in your script:

```
arcpy.ExportXYv_stats(output_speed_fc, "select the fields", "COMMA", "output_speed.txt" ,"ADD_FIELD_NAMES")
```